# How can I iterate through a list of strings in Python and concatenate the ones that belong to a tag?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, list

When iterating through a list of elements in Python 3, how can I 'isolate' the contents in between elements of interest?

I have a list:

```
list = ["<h1> question 1", "question 1 content", "question 1 more content", "<h1> answer 1", "answer 1 content", "answer 1 more content", "<h1> question 2", "question 2 content", "<h> answer 2", "answer 2 content"]
```

In this list, there are elements with the tag < h > and others without it. The idea is that the element that has this tag is the "header", and the following elements until the next tag are its contents.

How can I concatenate the elements of the list that belong to header to have two equal size lists:

```
headers = ["<h1> question 1", "<h1> answer 1", "<h1> question 2", "<h> answer 2"]
content = ["question 1 content question 1 more content", "answer 1 content answer 1 more content", "question 2 content", "answer 2 content"]
```

Where the length of these two lists are the same, in this case, 4 elements each.

I am able to get these partially separated, but you could use a little help to get to the end:

```
list = ["<h1> question 1", "question 1 content", "question 1 more content", "<h1> answer 1", "answer 1 content", "answer 1 more content", "<h1> question 2", "question 2 content", "<h> answer 2", "answer 2 content"]

headers = []
content = []

for i in list:
    if "<h1>" in i:
        headers.append(i)

    if "<h1>" not in i:
        tempContent = []
        tempContent.append(i)
        content.append(tempContent)
```

Any thoughts on how to combine these texts so that they map out 1 to 1?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming that after each header all elements are contents of that header, and that the first element is always a header - you can use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby).

The `key` can be whether the element has the header tag, and that way the contents of that header will be grouped right after it:

```py
from itertools import groupby

lst = ["<h1> question 1", "question 1 content", "question 1 more content", "<h1> answer 1", "answer 1 content", "answer 1 more content", "<h1> question 2", "question 2 content", "<h> answer 2", "answer 2 content"]

headers = []
content = []

for key, values in groupby(lst, key=lambda x: "<h" in x):
    if key:
        headers.append(*values)
    else:
        content.append(" ".join(values))

print(headers)
print(content)
```

Gives:

```
['<h1> question 1', '<h1> answer 1', '<h1> question 2', '<h> answer 2']
['question 1 content question 1 more content', 'answer 1 content answer 1 more content', 'question 2 content', 'answer 2 content']
```

---

The problem with your current approach is that you always add just one item to the contents. What you want to do is accumulate the `temp_content` list until you encounter the next header, and only then add it and reset:

```py
headers = []
content = []
temp_content = None

for i in list:
    if "<h" in i:
        if temp_content is not None:
            content.append(" ".join(temp_content))
            temp_content = []
        headers.append(i)

    else:
        temp_content.append(i)
```

Comment: @Pythoner happy to help. I added also a note about your current approach, for reference

Answer (score 1):

You could collect your headers and content in a [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) as you iterate the list. Then split the keys and values into `headers` and `content` lists at the end. We can detect headers by simply checking if a string [`str.startswith`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.startswith) `"<h"`.

I also use the [`continue`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#continue) statement to go to the next iteration immediately after finding a header. Can also just use an `else` statement here.

```
from collections import defaultdict

lst = [
    "<h1> question 1",
    "question 1 content",
    "question 1 more content",
    "<h1> answer 1",
    "answer 1 content",
    "answer 1 more content",
    "<h1> question 2",
    "question 2 content",
    "<h> answer 2",
    "answer 2 content",
]

header_map = defaultdict(list)

header = None
for item in lst:
    if item.startswith("<h"):
        header = item
        continue
    header_map[header].append(item)

headers = list(header_map)
print(headers)

content = [" ".join(v) for v in header_map.values()]
print(content)
```

**Output:**

```
['<h1> question 1', '<h1> answer 1', '<h1> question 2', '<h> answer 2']
['question 1 content question 1 more content', 'answer 1 content answer 1 more content', 'question 2 content', 'answer 2 content'
```